# Prove that $|f(x)|\leq|\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|+\int_{a}^{b}|f'(x)|dx$

Tags: calculus

where $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
Quite easily, $|\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|=|f(c)|$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. so it would be most ideal if $\int_{a}^{b}|f'(x)|dx\geq|f(x)-f(c)|$, which I suppose it is indeed the case here- but is there a rigorous way of proving $\int_{a}^{b}|f'(x)|dx\geq|f(x)-f(c)|$? I'm just taking a wild guess and drawing some graphs to convince myself its correct.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let us first  prove the following: if $g$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^{b} g(t)dt=0$ then $|g(x)| \leq \int_a^{b}|g'(t)|dt$ for all $x$.

Since $\int_a^{b} g(t)dt=0$ $g$ must take both positive and negative values. So there exist $c$ such that $g(c)=0$.  Now $g(x)=g(c)+\int_c^{x} g'(t)dt$ from which we get $|g(x)| \leq \int_a^{b}|g'(t)|dt$ for all $x$.

Now apply this to $g(x)=f(x)-\frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^{b} f(x)dx$ .

Comment: How did you get "from which we get $ |g(x)|≤\int_{a}^{b}g′(t)|dt$ for all $x$"? from $g(x)=g(c)+\int_{x}^{c}g′(t)dt$?

Comment: @MrPS $g(c)=0$ and the integral from $c$ to $x$ is less than or equal to integral from $a$ to $b$

Comment: Could you write the steps in detail? Thanks！“the integral from c to x is less than or equal to integral from a to b” is that supposed to be common sense?

Comment: Integral of a non-negative function over smaller interval does not exceed  the integral over a larger interval. @MrPS